# Fix subscript out of bounds error when adding column to df

Tags: r, subscript

I have a df with 20 columns of numerical data. I am trying to add an additional column with the "total" number of rows, however I am getting a subscript out of bounds error. This is the code I'm using:

```
df[,"Total"]<-rowSums(df)
```

This is the error:

```
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, , "Total", value = c(Acidovorax = 13, Acinetobacter = 48143,  : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

Comment: It seems like `df` is a matrix, not a `data.frame`. If that's intentional, then use `df <- cbind(df, Total = rowSums(df))`. If you don't think that's the case, then this code shouldn't fail like that. Please [edit] your question and provide the output from `dput(head(df))`. Thanks!

Comment: Yep that solved it. Fixed with as.data.frame()

Answer (score 1):

That shouldn't happen for `data.frame`s, but can for `matrix`.

```r
mt_mtx <- as.matrix(mtcars)

mtcars[,"Total"] <- rowSums(mtcars)
head(mtcars)
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb   Total
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 328.980
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 329.795
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 259.580
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 426.135
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 590.310
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 385.540

mt_mtx[,"Total"] <- rowSums(mt_mtx)
# Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, , "Total", value = c(`Mazda RX4` = 328.98, `Mazda RX4 Wag` = 329.795,  : 
#   subscript out of bounds
```

The quick remedy is to convert your `df` back to a `data.frame`. If you weren't expecting this, thinking that your `df` was *already* a frame, then I suggest you go back through your code to find what accidentally coerced it to a matrix.

Comment: I know it's the case, but I still don't understand *why* this is so. You can replace columns just fine `mt_mtx[, "carb"] <- 1`, but not create them. Anyway... enough postulating.

Comment: It was a head-scratching moment for me, too. It's R.